# TCL windows dll function that receive as argument and return a list

Tags: windows, list, dll, tcl

I am programming a dll in windows as extension for TCL and I need to create a function that receives as arguments a list and return also a list.
So far, I am dealing with simple arguments and returning only one value with:

```c
Tcl_SetDoubleObj(resultptr, val);
```

for example.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To parse a list, use `Tcl_ListObjGetElements()`. It will let you get an array of all the elements and then you can use operations like `Tcl_GetIntFromObj` and `Tcl_GetDoubleFromObj` to pick out the values from the elements (according to what you expect).

```
int listc, i;
Tcl_Obj **listv;

if (Tcl_ListObjGetElements(interp, objv[1], &listc, &listv) != TCL_OK) {
    return TCL_ERROR;
}

for (i = 0; i < listc; i++) {
    int val;
    if (Tcl_GetIntFromObj(interp, listv[i], &val) != TCL_OK) {
        return TCL_ERROR;
    }
    printf("I've got a %d at index %d\n", val, i);
}
```

The reverse direction is done with `Tcl_NewListObj`, `Tcl_NewIntObj` (or `Tcl_NewDoubleObj`, or `Tcl_NewStringObj`, or…) and `Tcl_SetObjResult`.

```
Tcl_Obj *elements[5];
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    elements[i] = Tcl_NewIntObj(i * i + 3);
}
Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, Tcl_NewListObj(5, elements));
```

In more complicated situation, you may need to manipulate the reference counts of values with `Tcl_IncrRefCount` and `Tcl_DecrRefCount`, but for these simple cases you don't need them.